# How to communicate data between wcf and wpf?

Tags: wpf, wcf, mvvm, mvvm-light

How do communicate data between wcf and wpf using entity framework 4, mvvm light?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in your question? At first reading, your question looks like it answers itself.

Comment: I want to know, how to create wcf data model entities clone code in wpf and then map it to actual data entities of data model

Comment: There are many, many tutorials on this. just google it.

Comment: Because there are many many tutorials, i dont get it. I want something simple and quick. Terms like POCO, Automapper, DTO, Serializer, Deserializer are all over the place, and there are more comparison articles that what to use instead of an article showing an implementation that works, all this make my head go round!! I just need a simple thing to communicate the data!

Comment: @NSingla: sorry, but it seems you need a clue. Here's one: make it work directly between WPF and a database first. That should teach you enough to come back here with a better question.

Comment: WCF is a big topic - you won't get something "simple and quick".  I strongly recommend the MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit - http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Book.aspx?ID=12486&locale=en-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too broad to answer fully in a single post.  Start by going through the tutorials on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx.)

To use publish and consume a WCF service, you need to learn about the following things:

1. Service Contracts
2. Data Contracts
3. Bindings
4. Hosting a service
5. Consuming a service

There is plenty of information available on these topics via Google.  If you get stuck on any point, post another question and someone should be able to help you.

Comment: I am already consuming the web service and I am able to bring the data to wpf, the thing I am missing is creating projection of data entities in wpf and mapping to wcf entities. Right now I am just passing the data, but not the right way I guess

Comment: That is not what your question says :)  This tutorial covers what you are after: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFHostingAndConsuming.aspx